# Datatable Function is Not working while all the required files are referenced

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

Here is the Bundle.Config File.

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace DataTableDemo
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                        "~/Scripts/datatables/jquery.datatables.js"  // This is the datatable script file.
                        ));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/datatables/datatables.bootstrap.js",  // This is the datatable bootstraip script file.
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/css/datatables.bootstrap.css",      // This is the datatable bootstrap css file.
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
    }
}
```

_Layout Page ! All the Scripts are rendered.

```
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Global.asax File... The Bundle's are configured.

```
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
```

This is the Index Page where the actual table lives.
look ! everything is fine. 
but DataTable is no showing in intellisense.
and in the Run mode. Datatable is not working.

(the query code is written at the bottom of the page...)

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<table id="students" class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Rehan Shah</td>
        <td>flyrehan786@gmail.com</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td>Pakistan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hamza Shah</td>
        <td>solday66@gmail.com</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td>Pakistan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Rizwan Ullah</td>
        <td>rizwanullah939@gmail.com</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td>Pakistan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mahboob Ur Rehman</td>
        <td>No Email</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td>Pakistan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Zeeshan Ali</td>
        <td>zali5095@gmail.com</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td>Pakistan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ahmad Saeed</td>
        <td>No Email</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td>Pakistan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hazrat Nawab</td>
        <td>No Email</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td>Pakistan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hameed Ali Shah</td>
        <td>HaliShah@gmail.com</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td>Pakistan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Irfan Ullah</td>
        <td>irfancsit555@gmail.com</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td>Pakistan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Adil Shah</td>
        <td>adil@gmail.com</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td>Pakistan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>BlaaBlaaBlaa</td>
        <td>BlaaBlaaBlaa</td>
        <td>BlaaBlaaBlaa</td>
        <td>BlaaBlaaBlaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>BlaaBlaaBlaa</td>
        <td>BlaaBlaaBlaa</td>
        <td>BlaaBlaaBlaa</td>
        <td>BlaaBlaaBlaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>BlaaBlaaBlaa</td>
        <td>BlaaBlaaBlaa</td>
        <td>BlaaBlaaBlaa</td>
        <td>BlaaBlaaBlaa</td>
    <tr>
        <td>BlaaBlaaBlaa</td>
        <td>BlaaBlaaBlaa</td>
        <td>BlaaBlaaBlaa</td>
        <td>BlaaBlaaBlaa</td>
    <tr>
        <td>BlaaBlaaBlaa</td>
        <td>BlaaBlaaBlaa</td>
        <td>BlaaBlaaBlaa</td>
        <td>BlaaBlaaBlaa</td>
    <tr>
        <td>BlaaBlaaBlaa</td>
        <td>BlaaBlaaBlaa</td>
        <td>BlaaBlaaBlaa</td>
        <td>BlaaBlaaBlaa</td>
    <tr>
        <td>BlaaBlaaBlaa</td>
        <td>BlaaBlaaBlaa</td>
        <td>BlaaBlaaBlaa</td>
        <td>BlaaBlaaBlaa</td>
    </tr>
</table>

@section scripts{
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            $("#students").DataTable();
        });
    </script>    
}
```

Output :

[image]
[image]

Comment: The css id used `$("#students").DataTable();` and  in html id is `randomDatatable` are different

Comment: Sorry....it was mistake during editing my question.  - Sumesh TG

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery("#students").DataTable();
        });`

Comment: and also check console for any js errors

Comment: Console is cleared when the page rendered in the browser.. -Ehsan Sajjad

Comment: Check those dependencies loading correctly

Comment: Today >>> from last 10 hours.. believe me i am stuck with this problem and don't understand  ! what is going wrong?????????????????????????????????

Comment: Yes i Checked......all the dependencies are loaded....i am going to add a screenshot as well...    - Sumesh TG

Comment: Please make sure the versions of bootstrap and datatables `datatables.bootstrap.css` are same

Comment: Bootstrap 3...... it think its correct version towards mvc default template. @SumeshTG

Comment: Please include js script in jquery main function. This `$("#students").DataTable();` appears in `<script>` tag did you see that?

Comment: @SumeshTG ... Main function ? can you please explain.

Comment: `<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            $("#students").DataTable();
        });
    </script>` see this snippet is not present in your screenshot.

Comment: SumeshTG..... i am going to add another screenshot. ..review it...still not working.

Comment: put an `alert` or `console.log` and make sure main is working.

Comment: i put this code...and it works fine...      `<script>
        console.log("Before");
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            $("#students").DataTable();
        });
        console.log("After");
    </script>`